# Django POST validation seeing number as string

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm a bit confused where to go with this as I thought it would be part of Django's validation... I'm on 1.8 because I'm using an older database connection library that was last tested with 1.8 (rewriting a frontend for old data).

models.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    #rest of class#
    RequestorNumber = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='requestor_no')

class Requestor(models.Model):
    RequestorNumber = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column="requester_no")
    Requestor = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column = "requester")

    def __str__(self):
         return self.Requestor
```

forms.py

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
RequestorNumber = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Requestor.objects.all().order_by('RequestorNumber'), label="Requestor")
```

So this creates a correct dropdown in the template, with values as integers and text as the descriptions ex:

```
<option value="1" selected="selected">JOHN DOE</option>
```

When the form is submitted, the POST QueryDict has a proper entry when printing the entire request:

```
...
'OrderForm-RequestorNumber': ['1']
...
```

but this is coming in as a string (as I would expect), but the validator when doing is_valid() kicks back and the webpage gets:

'JOHN DOE' value must be an integer.

Is this by design?  I feel like it's trying ignore the value of the selected for the form and referring back to the object's __str__ definition as what needs to be saved.  If this is dumb, i'm also all ears to figure out what a more correct method is, the only problem is I can't change the DB schema, and all tables are managed=False in the meta.

EDIT:  I overwrote the clean_RequestorNumber in the form to literally output the value it thinks is supposed to be saved, and it's giving the value of the __str__ of the method rather than the primary key.

I need to change this behavior but I can't nail down the spot in source code where the validation is being done. Between models.py, fields.py, and widgets.py i can see the required, valid_choice, and other validations but I can't spot where this is being pushed around.  Once I can spot it I can try writing my own class but I can't figure out what to overwrite.

Comment: Why isn't your RequestorNumber field a ForeignKey?

Comment: There are actually no key definitions on the database schema i'm using (straight out of 1993).  I wasn't sure what would happen with django if I defined a foreign key on a field and didn't define the db_column attribute and the database at the far side had no concept of a foreign key being in that field (and only values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['RequestorNumber'].choices = [(x.pk, x.Requestor) for x in Requestor.objects.all()]

RequestorNumber = forms.ChoiceField()
```

Doing it the old way before ModelChoiceField was a thing validates correctly.  Not sure if this was fixed past 1.8 but I'm still having trouble finding the spot in the source that would provide the incorrect behavior for the validation.  If someone can point me in the correct direction I'd be happy as I would still rather fix the version I'm on so I can have some cleaner code to deal with.  Going to leave this up for a week if someone can help and then just mark this as the answer.